# Loading spinner animation via keyframes - can't grasp the concept?

Tags: css, animation

I am learning CSS animations and I thought I understand conceptually how it works.

I decided to create a loading spinner: a div, whose width/height is 0, but whose borders are tuned to create "diamond" look:

[image]

Then idea is that there will be 5 "states" for animation of this spinner:

1. initial state 0 - full diamond is visible
2. state 1: left border on, all 3 others off
3. state 2: top border on, all others off
4. state 3: right border on, all others off
5. state 4: bottom border on, all others off

And I thought the above logic implementation is as easy as:

- create a div, add class "spinner" to it.
- in CSS style the div as initial state
- create animation reference
- create @keyframes animation: 0%,100% = initial state 0, 20% = state 1, 40% = state 2, 60% = state 3, 80% = state 4

Then make sure animation is set to infinite and thats it, so here is the implementation and it surely doesn't work as I expected above.

```css
.spinner {
  /* initial state 0 */:
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-left: 100px solid darkgrey;
  border-top: 100px solid lightgrey;
  border-right: 100px solid grey;
  border-bottom: 100px solid black;
  background-color: dimgrey;
  animation: spinning 3s infinite;
}
@keyframes spinning {
  0%, 100% {
/* initial state 0 */
border-left: 100px solid darkgrey;
border-top: 100px solid lightgrey;
border-right: 100px solid grey;
border-bottom: 100px solid black;
  }
  20% {
/* state 1 */
border-left: 100px solid darkgrey;
border-top: 100px solid transparent;
border-right: 100px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
  }
  40% {
/* state 2 */
border-left: 100px solid transparent;
border-top: 100px solid lightgrey;
border-right: 100px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
  }
  60% {
/* state 3 */
border-left: 100px solid transparent;
border-top: 100px solid transparent;
border-right: 100px solid grey;
border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
  }
  80% {
/* state 4 */
border-left: 100px solid transparent;
border-top: 100px solid transparent;
border-right: 100px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 100px solid black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner"></div>
```

**What am I missing here? I want to understand what logic css animations are following? I read some articles at CSS tricks but those are more working examples and I want to grasp concept behind;/ any suggestions?**

UPDATE: seems like I left some commas;( fixing the example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commas and colons in your `keyframes` definition are breaking it. Remove them so it looks like this:

```
@keyframes spinning {
  0%, 100% {
    /* initial state 0 */
    border-left: 100px solid darkgrey;
    border-top: 100px solid lightgrey;
    border-right: 100px solid grey;
    border-bottom: 100px solid black;
  }
  20% {
    /* state 1 */
    border-left: 100px solid darkgrey;
    border-top: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
  }
  40% {
    /* state 2 */
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid lightgrey;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
  }
  60% {
    /* state 3 */
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid grey;
    border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
  }
  80% {
    /* state 4 */
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid black;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ouch;) but the understanding i have is in fact correct then?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko Yes. Fix the keyframes and it will work.